# Add file size criteria to Directory.EnumerateFiles LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

Using LINQ I would like to retrieve all files under a given directory that are less/greater than a specified file size.

I have the following code that returns a List at present:

```
    public static List<string> getFs(string sDir)
    {
        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(s => s.ToLower().EndsWith(".psd"));

        return files.ToList();
    }
```

I found the following code courtesy of Monsieur Skeet that seems to access file size:

```
long diskSpace = (from directory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(@"c:\")
              from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory)
              select file)
             .Sum(file => new FileInfo(file).Length);
```

How would I adapt the file size aspect of this into my existing code or is this the wrong approach in the context of what I have already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add an additional `Where`... As an example:

```
public static List<string> getFs(string sDir) 
{ 
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories) 
        .Where(s => s.ToLower().EndsWith(".psd"))
        .Where(s => new FileInfo(s).Length > 10000); 

    return files.ToList(); 
}
```

Of course, you could also combine the two `Where` clauses; I kept them separate for clarity. This is equally valid:

```
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories) 
        .Where(s => s.ToLower().EndsWith(".psd") && new FileInfo(s).Length > 1000000);
```

Comment: @GHarping I certainly didn't downvote you... your question is perfectly valid.

Comment: Ah, many apologies, your answer coincided almost to the second with this scandalous downvoting atrocity. Thanks very much for the help.